# Multiple Return Types with templates and switch case in C++

Tags: c++, templates, enums, return

I am trying to get a multiple return type function working in C++, by providing an enum value as a template argument.

Here is my code:

```
static enum class TEXTAttribute {
    ORIGIN_PROPORTION, FONT_NAME
};

struct MyStruct {
    std::string font_name;
    sf::Vector2f origin_proportion;
};
template<TEXTAttribute ATTRIBUTE>
auto GetTextAttribute(const MyStruct& style){
    switch (ATTRIBUTE) {
    case TEXTAttribute::FONT_NAME: {return style.font_name; break; }
    case TEXTAttribute::ORIGIN_PROPORTION: {return style.origin_proportion; break; }
    }
}
int main() {
    GetTextAttribute<TEXTAttribute::FONT_NAME>(MyStruct{});
}
```

I thought I would be able to do this since I am using auto? I just seem to get an error saying that the return type was unable to be deduced. Is this even possible?

Comment: Even though `ATTRIBUTE` is known at compile time, `switch` statement check it at runtime. So as far as the compiler is concerned, both `return` statements could run, and they attempt to return different types. `if constexpr` might work; `std::conditional` definitely would.

Answer (score 1):

There's no problem deducing the `auto`, but the issue is that `auto` deduces to different return types. If you want to have different return types, you need a compile construct such as `if constexpr`:

```
template<TEXTAttribute ATTRIBUTE>
auto GetTextAttribute(const std::array<MyStruct,3> statestyles) {
    auto& style = statestyles.at(0);
    if constexpr(ATTRIBUTE == TEXTAttribute::FONT_NAME)  
        return style.font_name;
    else if constexpr(ATTRIBUTE == TEXTAttribute::ORIGIN_PROPORTION)  
       return style.origin_proportion;
}
```

Comment: Is this considered bad practice in a case like this?

Answer (score 1):

What you want is semi-possible, but not with `switch`. You have to use C++17's `if constexpr`:

```
template<TEXTAttribute ATTRIBUTE>
auto GetTextAttribute(const std::array<MyStruct,3> statestyles)
{
    auto& style = statestyles.at(0);
    if constexpr(ATTRIBUTE == TEXTAttribute::FONT_NAME)
        return style.font_name;
    if constexpr(ATTRIBUTE == TEXTAttribute::ORIGIN_PROPORTION)
        return style.origin_proportion;
}
```

The untaken `return` branches are discarded, since `ATTRIBUTE` is a template parameter.

Comment: Wow, posted at exactly the same time :)

Comment: Is this considered good or bad practice? Wouldn't the if /else take a lot more time than the switch case?

Comment: No, in fact, this is technically more efficient, since there is no run time cost of a `switch`.

Comment: If there is no run time cost of a switch, wouldn't that make it more efficient? (Sorry newbie here)

Comment: @jasbindra00: "*Is this considered good or bad practice?*" It's ultimately no different from how `tuple`'s `get` function` works. "*Wouldn't the if /else take a lot more time than the switch case?*" It's *`constexpr`*; by definition, the conditional test is resolved at compile time. That's what allows it to discard the `return` statements.

Answer (score 0):

`switch` is a runtime construct. Use `if constexpr`:

```cpp
    if constexpr (ATTRIBUTE == TEXTAttribute::FONT_NAME) return style.font_name;
    else if constexpr(ATTRIBUTE == TEXTAttribute::ORIGIN_PROPORTION) {
        return style.origin_proportion;
    }
```

Just remember to put all the parameter value-dependent code in appropirate `if constexpr`/`else` branches.